# Incorrect syntax near '.'. While Update a variable table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

I have an issue while updating a table variable. I've already declared it, however when I run the whole query I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

And I can't seem to solve the issue...

```
UPDATE @List 
SET nrID = CASE 
              WHEN nrID IS NULL 
                 THEN t1.nrID 
                 ELSE nrID 
           END 
FROM @List 
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON @List.PNr = t1.PNr
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.n nrPNr = t2.nrPNr
WHERE t1.PNr = t2.PNr AND t2.Isactive = 0
```

Comment: try taking out the table name from here 'SET @List.nrID', you've already told it what table you're updating.

Comment: You gave table2 the alias of "O" but you're joining on the alias of "t2".  There is no "t2" defined in your code.

Comment: Further more, if you're joining on `nrID` to `table1` - your set/case statement is redundant, `@List.nrID` will never be null since its a join predicate, and null cannot join to anything as it can't be evaluated for equality.  In other words, you inner join to `table1` immediately removes all rows with a null `@List.nrID`.-- so every row matched will just wind up being updated to `@List.nrID`.

Comment: Thanks, It was a wrong typo. (I changed the code). However, what I want is to check if the value in the @List column is null and if it is, I want to populate it with an ID from two other tables (t1 & t2). However if there's no match it should just leave it at null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help, changed my declared @table to create @temptable and it took away my incorrect syntax error.

As for the query I Used (example);

```
UPDATE Person
   SET Car = ISNULL(@Car, Car),
       HairColour = ISNULL(@HairColour, HairColour),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE List 
SET List.nrID = t1.nrID
FROM @List AS List
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON List.nrID = t1.nrID
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.nrID = t2.nrID
WHERE t1.nrID = t2.nrID AND t2.Isactive = 0
```

As mentioned in the comments the inner join will remove any nulls in your case

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UPDATE L
SET L.nrID = ISNULL(t1.nrID, t2.nrID)
FROM @List L
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON L.PNr = t1.PNr
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.nrPNr = t2.nrPNr
WHERE t1.PNr = t2.PNr
    AND t2.Isactive = 0
```